# How do I copy a folder between SVN repositories?

Tags: svn

I have checked out a folder from one svn repository and now I am trying to copy it into another repository. I used the following command:

```
svn cp -m "Replace 35GB sql dud commit with empty file" /u01/tmp/35gb_tmp_dir/ file:///u01/master/Labs/Analytics/Code/
```

This gives me an error:

```
svn: E235000: In file 'subversion/libsvn_client/copy.c' line 1386: assertion failed (commit_items != NULL)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I guess it is due to the modified file not being comitted or something, not sure.

Comment: Repairing or preparing? If the former, what does this mean? What is the "dud" commit? Do you want to delete the 35GB file from every revision?

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: `svn copy` does not allow any cross repository copying. (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.copy.html). For the new repository you just need to add and commit or import the file, but you cannot preserve the history

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, take your time and read the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/index.html), please. What you are trying to do is totally unclear and the commands that you run do not look right. What is more, the `assertion failed` error that you receive is most likely a bug. I guess that you use a very-very outdated SVN version and you must update it. Most likely, the bug is fixed now.

On SVN to Git migration topic, how are you planning to use and maintain a repository with huge files in Git? Think about it and plan accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 'svn cp' just use 'svn import'. This assumes that what you are importing is being added to the repository for the first time i.e. has no history.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error. My wc url is not the same root of target,
wc url is svn://username@xxx.xxx.cc/pro, target is svn://xxx.xxx.cc/pro, use svn relocate and it's work for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).